# Returning a collection in collection from controller to twig in Symfony

Tags: symfony, object, collections, twig

I guess this is pretty easy but I am a novice at Symfony so I got troubles with it.

So basiccaly here is what I got in Controller

```
public function pollResultsAction( $pollId ) {

    $poll = $this->get('doctrine')->getRepository('Myproject:Poll')->find( $pollId );

    $questions = $poll->getItems();

    return array(   
        'questions' => $poll->getItems()
    );
}
```

where $questions is a Collection of questions of the Poll given

then I have

```
 {% if questions %}
      <ul>
        {% for question in questions %}
    <li>    {{ question.question }}</li>

          // here I'd like to have answers to given question
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
```

in a Twig file.

I can get to answers like this

```
$answer = $onequestion->getAnswers();
```

I'd like to print answers to each question in twig. I think I need to some foreach loop in controller but I don't know how to return it to twig.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your view:

```
{% for question in questions %}
   {{ qustion.question }}
   {% for answer in question.answers %}
      {{ answer }}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: But how I get to one question? $questions is a collections and each question has a collection of answers.